# WSO2 API Manager How to configure custom domain and SSL

Tags: ssl, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can i configure custom domain name and CA certified SSL certificates for WSO2 API Mananger.
I have WSO2 configured in AWS EC2.

Answer (score 1):

To have a custom domain name in your API Manager change the `<MgtHostName>` and the `<HostName>` in your carbon.xml in {AM_HOME}/repository/conf directory as instructed in this [reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Configuring+carbon.xml).

e.g.

```
<HostName>abc.com</HostName>
<MgtHostName>abc.com</MgtHostName>
```

Follow [this article](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/) on how to add the CA Signed Certificate to WSO2 Products and you can do the same with WSo2 API Manager to get your task done.

Comment: is there a chance that i can remove the port number from urls?

Comment: you can set proxy ports (80 and 443) in `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml` . http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/proxy-howto.html